# Background change on click not working

Tags: jquery, css

The following code is supposed to change the background color of the item clicked on. The radio button switches correctly but both items change color and stay that way. I would appreciate any help.

```
<style>
div.borderOn  {border:2px solid #555; background-color:#666}
div.borderOff {border:0px; background-color:#fff} 
</style>

<div>
   <div id="sUL"><label id="lUL"><input id="isUL" type="radio" name="shadow_group" value="shadowUL">&nbsp;Shadow UL</label></div>
   <div id="sUR"><label id="lUR"><input id="isUR" type="radio" name="shadow_group" value="shadowUR">&nbsp;Shadow UR</label></div>
</div>

<script>
$("label").click(function() {
var bClass = "";

bClass = ( $("#isUL").is(":checked") ? "borderOn" : "borderOff");
$("#sUL").addClass(bClass);

bClass = ( $("#isUR").is(":checked") ? "borderOn" : "borderOff");
$("#sUR").addClass(bClass);
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/52k7pyd8/

Comment: Is this what you're after https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/52k7pyd8/1/?

Comment: That' exactly what I needed. I've been working on this for hours,  Thank you very much. :)